# Pandas : Create dummy variables based on conditions in 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe of dummy variables (0/1) based on conditions in two different dataframes, `df` and `dfLag`.  Both `df` and `dfLag` have the same columns / dimensions.

Consider the following dataframe and it's lag:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':(0,0,0,0,14,15,16,17),
    'b':(20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27),
    'c':(30,31,32,0,34,35,36,37),
    'd':(40,41,42,43,44,0,0,47),
})

dfLag = df.shift(1)
```

I would like to create a new dataframe `dummies` that is 1 if the corresponding element in both `df` and `dfLag` is greater than 0, and 0 otherwise.

Below illustrates the expected output.  I have no idea how to go about this...

[image]

Comment: does it have to be separate dfs? if not `df.apply(lambda x: np.where(x.gt(0) & x.shift(1).gt(0),1 ,0))`

Comment: @AsishM.  This worked perfectly, thank you!  If you write up as the solution, I will accept.  Otherwise I can write up later.

Comment: You can go ahead

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Will do.